# npm install Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net, npm, devops

Please help me set up npm install tall for the project. My project is on the gitlab, I set up the pipeline and release it. I do not understand which folder path I need to specify npm install, since only files from artifacts give me a choice. Perhaps I configured the pipeline incorrectly?

[folder1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwOPD.png)
[folder2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPcY3.png)

Comment: Hey, please name your images. Normally the work dir is the root folder. Are you run own a self hostet agend or one offered by Ms?

Comment: Hello @KargWare I am own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you just need to write a script (npm install)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QRb8.png) in your pipeline for releases